# How to Limit Wifi Connection to Only One Application?

Tags: macos, wifi, security, vpn

I need to connect to open Wifi network but I do not want all my applications access internet with it. Only one internet browser.

I am using at the moment VPN Service PrivateInternetAccess.com (PIA). 
I need Latvian internet access. I need to one wifi connection use Latvian Open Wifi Connection, and let it use only one specific browser. Otherwise, my other Wifi will use my cell phone internet that is connected to PIA's VPN.

---

How can you restrict only one internet browser access internet with open wifi connection?

Comment: Do you want the application internet restriction to apply only when you have WiFi, or every time?

Comment: Only when I am in specific wifi. I need the specific wifi to get access to some materials that are accessible only in one country. Otherwise, I do not want to have the restriction. I just do not want that my private communication goes in unprotected wifi.

Answer (score 2):

Use Little Snitch 3 for that.

You can use Automatic Profile Switching for your filter rules depending on the network you are in.

For your specific WiFi just block everything except your browser for that.

https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html

[image: Little Snitch Automatic Profile Switching]